Hide fields in child class when inheriting
Is it really impossible to hide these two fields in the inspector of the child class when inheriting, without using a custom inspector?
If yes, then what is the best way to change the value of currentState in the EnemyBattleLogic class?
Thanks!

public class EnemyMoveLogic : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, Range(1f, 10f)] internal float movingSpeed;
    [SerializeField] internal float detectionDistance;

    internal GameObject player;
    internal NavMeshAgent agent;

    internal enum CurrentState
    {
        Sleep,
        Patrol,
        Chase
    }

    internal CurrentState currentState = CurrentState.Sleep;




public class EnemyBattleLogic : EnemyMoveLogic
{
    [SerializeField, Range(1f, 5000f)] internal float health;
    [SerializeField, Range(1f, 5000f)] internal float damage;
    [SerializeField, Range(0.1f, 3f)] internal float attackSpeed;
    [SerializeField] internal float attackDistance;


Why are you using the internal keyword here?

you should ask yourself: is an EnemyBattleLogic really an EnemyMoveLogic, or does it just happen to have some common members and rather use some EnemyMoveLogic in some way? In other words: favour composition over inheritance.

I need the internal to access fields from other classes, for example, to display the enemy's HP, which is implemented through GetComponent. However, I'm not sure if using GetComponent for everything is a good solution

I would say that the second option is correct, I'll check it now, thank you!


No, you can't hide those fields if you inherit them. Try using split components to have different logic and fields.
To change current state you can change it through inspector if you put [SerealizedField], or if it is meant to be changed in-code you can make public functions like SetStateSleep, SetStatePatrol, etc. This is useful when you want to add some event calls in these functions or some other logic in future.

These were the straight answers to your questions but it seems there are some tips that could help you to never have those questions.

If you don't need some variables or logic you shouldn't inherit them. If you only need some part of fields or/and logic you might need to split your base class as there are different behaviours.
Also in your screenshot I see EnemyMoveLogic and EnemyBattleLogic at the same time. You want to change the values only in EnemyMoveLogic. Then it seems you aren't supposed to have EnemyMoveLogic inherited but just another component. So you will just have these:

public class EnemyMoveLogic : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, Range(1f, 10f)] internal float movingSpeed;
    [SerializeField] internal float detectionDistance;

    internal GameObject player;
    internal NavMeshAgent agent;

    internal enum CurrentState
    {
        Sleep,
        Patrol,
        Chase
    }

    internal CurrentState currentState = CurrentState.Sleep;

    public void SetStateSleep()
    {
        // Some other logic
        currentState = CurrentState.Sleep;
        //Some other logic
    }

    // Other State change funcs...
}

// You can also split this class as there might be units that don't attack
// absurd but happened in my game
public class EnemyUnitLogic : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField, Range(1f, 5000f)] internal float health;
    [SerializeField, Range(1f, 5000f)] internal float damage;
    [SerializeField, Range(0.1f, 3f)] internal float attackSpeed;
    [SerializeField] internal float attackDistance;
}

There are lots of other ideas to make the code better but it would be incorrect to leave this under this question. It could be a huge discussion. Don't worry, the expirience comes in time.
